# Is every unitary operator a self-adjoint one?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, unitary-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional inner product  space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $T:X\to X$ be a linear map.  Then is the following true?

1. $T$ is unitary implies $T$ is self-adjoint

I think this is correct. $T$ is unitary implies that $T^{\theta} T=TT^{\theta}=1$. This means that  $\langle T^{\theta}T(x), y\rangle=\langle x, y\rangle$ where $T^{\theta}$ is complex conjuate of the matrix of $T$. This further means that $\langle T(x), y\rangle=\langle x, T(y)\rangle$, i.e. $T$ is self-adjoint.

Have I done it correctly or I am missing something?

Comment: $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}?$

Comment: $iI$ is a  counter-example. ($I$ is the identity operator).

Comment: The "This further means" is wrong. A unitary operator is self-adjoint iff it is a reflection in some subspace, i.e. iff $X$ is the orthogonal sum of the eigenspaces to the eigenvalues $1$ and $-1$ (if we allow an eigenspace to be $\{0\}$).

Comment: After "this further means" should follow $\langle T(x),T(y)\rangle=\langle x,y\rangle$ rather than what you wrote.